# Page up / down KeyEvent not being triggered on Google TV

Tags: android-activity, google-tv, keyevent

I have an activity in GTV with a layout containing a horizontal ScrollView inside a vertical ScrollView. The horizontal ScrollView contains lots of buttons, arranged in rows using nested vertical and horizontal linear layouts. (In case you are wondering why anybody would design such a crazy UI, this is an EPG for TV!)

In my code for the activity, I am overriding onKeyDown, and carrying out various custom actions, for certain key presses. This works fine, except for the page-up & page-down keys. Any code I place under *case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PAGE_DOWN:* simply does not get run. In fact the onKeyDown method doesn't get triggered at all, when these keys are pressed.

However I can see that the OS is receiving these key presses, and is acting on them (the page is being scrolled up & down).

I have tested this on 2 different physical GTV devices (from different manufacturers) and the problem exists on both.

If anybody can suggest a solution, I'd be mighty thankful :)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things (since you did not post any code) I am making some assumptions.

1. The KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PAGE_DOWN - you probably want KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN instead (likewise KEYCODE_DPAD_UP - I don't see a page up/page down key on my remote - just dpad.
2. Since you are handling the key events yourself you should be returning true on the onKeyDown implementation - otherwise the system may swallow your keyevent.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but no its not a case of confusing page-down with dpad-down. The remotes for both devices I'm using for testing have separate page-up/down keys and dpad-up/down keys, and they cause different results, so the OS is not treating them as the same thing. Also, I'm aware of the requirement to return true when my code handles the keyevent. I am handling several other keys in this same code block, and they all work as expected. I have confirmed that the onKeyDown method is not being triggered by page-up/down by writing logs every time it runs.

Comment: BTW the devices I'm testing with are a Logitech Revue and a Sony NSZ-GT1.

Comment: Are you sure that you are actually getting KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PAGE_DOWN? That is, on Vizio there was an issue of incorrect key mappings - I wonder if you might be experiencing something similar. I typically use https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googledevrel.android.tv.sample.basicresolutiontest&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5nb29nbGVkZXZyZWwuYW5kcm9pZC50di5zYW1wbGUuYmFzaWNyZXNvbHV0aW9udGVzdCJd to test key codes when I am uncertain.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the keys you want are KEYCODE_CHANNEL_UP and KEYCODE_CHANNEL_DOWN, these at least map to the page up/channel up and page down/channel down keys on the Sony remote control.